# How can I update tensor (weight value) trying to use two separate network?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been trying to make AI for blackjack using RL. Now I'm trying to make two separate networks which is one way of DQN. I've searched the web and found some way and tried to use it but failed.

This error has occurred:

> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

Code:

```
import gym
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def one_hot(x):
    s=np.identity(600)
    b = s[x[0] * 20 + x[1] * 2 + x[2]]
    return b.reshape(1, 600)

def boolstr_to_floatstr(v): 
if v == True:
    return 1
elif v == False:
    return 0

env=gym.make('Blackjack-v0')
learning_rate=0.5


state_number=600
action_number=2
#######################################3
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1,state_number], name='input_data')
W1=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([state_number,128],0,0.01))#network for update
layer1=tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X,W1))


W2=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([128,256],0,0.01))
layer2=tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(layer1,W2))

W3=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([256,action_number],0,0.01))
Qpred=tf.matmul(layer2,W3) # Qprediction
#####################################################################3
X1=tf.placeholder(shape=[1,state_number],dtype=tf.float32)
W4=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([state_number,128],0,0.01))#network for target
layer3=tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X1,W4))


W5=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([128,256],0,0.01))
layer4=tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(layer3,W5))

W6=tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([256,action_number],0,0.01))
target=tf.matmul(layer4,W6) # target
#################################################################

update1=W4.assign(W1)
update2=W5.assign(W2)
update3=W6.assign(W3)

Y=tf.placeholder(shape=[1,action_number],dtype=tf.float32)

loss=tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(Y-Qpred))#cost(W)=(Ws-y)^2
train=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)





num_episodes=1000 
dis=0.99 #discount factor
rList=[] #record the reward

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(num_episodes): #episode 만번
        s = env.reset()
        rALL = 0
        done = False
        e=1./((i/100)+1) #exploit or explore용 상수
        total_loss=[]
        while not done:  

            s = np.asarray(s)
            s[2] = boolstr_to_floatstr(s[2])
            #print(np.shape(one_hot(s)))
            #print(one_hot(s))
            Qs=sess.run(Qpred,feed_dict={X:one_hot(s).astype(np.float32)})


            if np.random.rand(1)<e:   #새로운 도전시도
                 a=env.action_space.sample()

            else:
                 a=np.argmax(Qs) #그냥 내가아는한 최댓값의 액션 선택



            s1,reward,done,_=env.step(a)  #
            s1=np.asarray(s1)
            s1[2]=boolstr_to_floatstr(s1[2])

            if done:
                Qs[0,a]=reward

            else:
                Qs1=sess.run(target,feed_dict={X1:one_hot(s1)})

                Qs[0,a]=reward+dis*np.max(Qs1) #optimal Q

            sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:one_hot(s),Y:Qs})
            if i%10==0: ##target 을 Qpredion으로 업데이트해줌
                sess.run(update1,update2,update3)

        if reward==1:
            rALL += reward
        else:
            rALL+=0
        s=s1

        rList.append(rALL)



print('success rate: '+ str(sum(rList)/num_episodes))
print("Final Q-table values")
```

I need to print success rate finally. before DQN its 38%ish. If there is something wrong in my code considering its DQN algorithm, tell me please.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the weights between different networks, then simply create layer with same name, using the scope `with tf.variable_scope(self.name, reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):` and then weights between networks will be shared automatically.

Comment: thanks for answering. but what i want to do is update the target network every 10 episodes not always.